# Application of Montel's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, arzela-ascoli, blaschke-products

**I am working on the following problem:**

Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the set of functions which are analytic on a neighborhood of the closed unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$. Find:

$$\sup\{|f(0)|\mid f(1/2)=0=f(1/3) \text{ and } |f(z)|\leq 1 \text{ when } |z|=1\}$$

Is the supremum attained? *Hint*: consider the function $\frac{z-1/2}{1-z/2}\frac{z-1/3}{1-z/3}$.

**Here are my thoughts so far:**

I know that by the maximum modulus principle, $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for all $|z|\leq 1$. By Montel's theorem, the new subfamily of $\mathcal{F}$, call it $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}$, is precompact.

**Q:** However, I am not sure if $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}$ is closed and so I cannot see if it is compact.

**Q:** Secondly, I understand the hint function to be a finite Blaschke product. Moreover, I see why the hint function belongs to $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}$, but I fail to see how this is helpful in computing the supremum.

Thank you for any hints/help!

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexhange. The subfamily $\tilde{ \mathcal{F}}$ is an intersection of closed stes, hence it is closed. It also contains the finite Blaschke product given there. What other functions can it contain?

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply. If we refer to the function in the hint as $h$, I think $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}$ should also contain $hf$ where $f\in\mathcal{F}$. I will think on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We only need the maximum modulus principle, not Montel's theorem.

The Blaschke product $B(z) = \frac{z-1/2}{1-z/2}\frac{z-1/3}{1-z/3}$ has modulus one for $|z| = 1$, and zeros in the unit disk only at $z=1/2$ and $z=1/3$. It follows that
$$
 g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{B(z)}
$$
has removable singularities, i.e. can be continued to a holomorphic function in the unit disk $\Bbb D$.

Then $|g(z)| \le 1$ for $|z|=1$, and therefore $|g(z)| \le 1$ in $\Bbb D$ because of the maximum modulus principle. In particular,
$$
 |f(0)| \le |B(0)| = \frac 1 6
$$
for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$. Equality holds for $f=B$, so that the supremum *is* attained.